# Selection of activation function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am making a AutoEncoder on Tensorflow which takes input as a 3 D Matrix whose value lie in the range of [-1,1]. What is the optimal activation function for this scenario?

Also, what is the rule of thumb in selecting the activation function w.r.t to the input ranges?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is generally advisable to start the network with batch normalization, which would more or less confine the values between -1 and 1 anyway.

The activation function of the hidden layers should have non-linearity to be able handle higher levels of complexity. So I'd choose **relu** or one of its variants.

At the end of the network, at the last layer, you can have a dense layer with no activation function to allow for mapping the negative values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Rule of thumb" when it comes to picking an activation function.

I use [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/understanding-activation-functions-in-deep-learning/) guide to pick my activation function depending on the complexity

Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34248291/8277802) answer for some more guidance